# How can i install AA Text Font in Joomla Editor

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5

I am very new in Joomla and i am creating a online exam website, but i need a editor that can understand Hindi but when i copy the text from Corel Draw to editor then it is not recognizing the text, so please can you tell me how can i solve this problem or some other plugin is available here for Hindi Editor.

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to add the appropriate language pack to TinyMCE, which is the default editor for Joomla. You can download the appropriate language pack from [here](http://www.tinymce.com/i18n/index.php?ctrl=lang&act=download).

In Joomla 1.6 and up, you would want to unzip this and upload the folders to this location:

```
media\editors\tinymce\jscripts\tiny_mce
```

For more information, I recommend browsing this blog post: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2381935

Joomla 1.5 uses a different location for the files:

```
plugins\editors\tinymce\jscripts\tiny_mce
```

If you are building a new site, I highly recommend using Joomla 2.5 instead of 1.5. 1.5 is no longer supported and 2.5 has a lot of improvements that will make setting up your site easier.

Comment: But how can i add my font in Joomla website. currently i am not able to install new font here.